# Writing a cronjob using a script

Tags: shell, jenkins, cron

This is the first time I am trying to setup the cronjob to automatically do updates in Jenkins.
Currently, I have done the following so far:

```
1. sudo crontab -e # opens  the cron tab which will/should put the file in /var/spool/cron
2. @daily yum update  # running  the updates daily
```

This fixes  the issue but

1. when I try to do `sudo cd /var/spool/cron` I cannot see any `crontab`. But  when I do `sudo crontab -l` it shows me `@daily yum updates`
2. How can I write the content `@daily yum updates` to `crontab` via script (like cloud init script)?

Answer (score 0):

One way is -

```
#write out current crontab
crontab -l > mycron
#echo new cron into cron file
echo "@daily yum updates" >> mycron
#install new cron file
crontab mycron
rm mycron
```

Comment: After adding that and spinning up new jenkins, when I am trying to do `sudo crontab -l` it says `no crontab for root`

Comment: further, why are you doing `rm mycron`?

Comment: Which user is executing this command? It should add a crib tab for that user. The micron is a temporary file used to load the entries in crontab, if you will do man crontab you can ready the arguments it takes and removing it at last is a nice practise

Comment: root, further, may I know if I put the command in /etc/cron.d/patch file it will be called automatically as a cronjob? `echo "0 3 * * * root yum -d 0 -y update > /dev/null 2>&1 && shutdown -r +1" >> /etc/cron.d/patch`? If yes, should I just delete the previous one?